# How can we host a taskpane.html in a local dev server? As I know, office.js does not allow it to be loaded outside the office app

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, add-in

I do hope I can load the taskpane.html outside the office app, which is for powerpoint add-ins actually. Because I need to run automation test. As I know, the office.js does not allow users to use it outside the office app. What should I do? Please.

Answer (score 1):

The taskpane.html can load in an ordinary browser, but you will get an error saying that Office.js cannot initialize. You can click buttons and other UI in the taskpane, but nothing that requires Office.js will work. If it is unit tests that you want to automate, you can do that with the mocking framework. See [Office Add-ins Unit Testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/unit-testing).

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to run the automation test using  PowerPoint on the Web (Office 365)?

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."